# Handle sign-up failure fails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did make a attribute called `address` before . But I didn't use it in the sign up form . When I input all text field in sign up form , it flashes the error

> The form contains 1 error.
>
> Address can't be blank

Any other places I should check with ?

Controller

```
 def new
        @tutor = Tutor.new
      end
      def create
        @tutor = Tutor.new(tutor_params)
        if @tutor.save
          log_in @tutor
          flash[:success] = "Congratulations! Your registration is successful!"
          redirect_to @tutor
        else
          render 'tutors/new'
        end
      end
    # Handle sign-up failure, to redirect the tutor to the registeration form again
      def tutor_params
        params.require(:tutor).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:gender 
          ,:education_level,:institution,:exprience,:district,:subject,:student_level)
      end
```

Sign Up page

```
     <%= form_for(@tutor) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>



 <%= f.label :gender %>
            <%= f.select(:gender, ['Male', 'Female'] , class: 'form-control' )%>


      <%= f.label :tutor_education_level %>
                <%= f.select(:education_level, ['Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctor'] , class: 'form-control' )%>


      <%= f.label :tutor_institution %>
      <%= f.text_field :institution, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :tutorial_experience %>
      <%= f.text_field :experience, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :tutor_preferred_district %>
      <%= f.text_field :district, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :tutor_preferred_subject %>
      <%= f.text_field :subject, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :tutor_required_student_level %>

       <%= f.select(:student_level, ['P1-P3', 'P4-P6', 'S1-S3', 'S4-S6'] , class: 'form-control' )%>


      <%= f.submit "Create tutor's account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
```

_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @tutor.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@tutor.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @tutor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

## db/schema.rb(uupdate)

```
  create_table "tutors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "education_level"
    t.string   "institution"
    t.integer  "experience"
    t.string   "district"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "student_level"
  end

  add_index "tutors", ["email"], name: "index_tutors_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "tutors", ["remember_token"], name: "index_tutors_on_remember_token"

end
```

## tutor.rb (update2)

```
`class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
    before_save :create_remember_token
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :address, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
end
`
```

Comment: Can you please share tutor model

Comment: When you render to new action it overwrites @tutor object.

Comment: @Sajin  what file I should show

Comment: Please post your `tutor.rb` model.

Comment: please share tutor.rb file inside app/models

Comment: @Sajin  done .``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
validates :address, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}
```

to

```
validates :address, length: {maximum: 100}
```

in your model tutor.rb

You are validating for the presence of address field in your model while creating a tutor, but you are not passing address params.

If you want to delete existing address field from db,
In your terminal, do

```
rails g migration remove_address_from_tutors
```

Add the following code in your newly created migration file

```
class RemoveAddressFromTutors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :tutors, :address
  end
end
```

and then do `rake db:migrate` in your terminal

Comment: As this `address` attribute is useless now ,how to del this attribute from the model

Comment: You will have to create a migration to remove this field from db

Comment: Can I directly del the `create` migration file or del the `address` line on `schema.rb`

Comment: No that is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: `proper way` means it is possible ,but not suggested ?

Comment: schema.rb is a schematic representaion of your database. Updating that file doesn't change the actual db. To change the actual db, you will have to create a migration and do `rake db:migrate`. This will change your schema.rb to your current db structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
        @tutor = Tutor.new(tutor_params)
        if @tutor.save
          log_in @tutor
          flash[:success] = "Congratulations! Your registration is successful!"
          redirect_to @tutor
        else
          flash[:tutor] = @tutor
          redirect_to new_tutor_path
        end
      end
```

Also make sure your validates_presence_of :address in your tutor model.